# How to add new layout via local.xml?

Tags: magento, layout, content-management-system

How can I add a new layout in magento using local.xml? I want it to appear in layouts list when I make new CMS page.

Comment: I cannot be done this way. The values for the page layout dropdowns are read from config XML.

Answer (score 0):

**Layout in magento using local.xml**

> *please go and follow this code.*

http://www.codeboss.in/web-funda/2009/07/07/create-new-layout-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the very last block of code on [this page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/adding_cms_layout_templates). You can go into `app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml` and add lines like this:

```
 <TEMPLATE_LABEL module="page" translate="label">
     <label>TEMPLATE NAME</label>
     <template>page/TEMPLATE-FILENAME.phtml</template>
     <layout_handle>page_HANDLE_NAME</layout_handle>
 </TEMPLATE_LABEL>
```

replacing the capitalized words, e.g.

```
 <home_format module="page" translate="label">
     <label>Home Format</label>
     <template>page/home-page.phtml</template>
     <layout_handle>page_home_format</layout_handle>
 </home_format>
```

Right before the end of the `<page> ... </page>` block of code.

**Note**: if you do it this way, you may not be able to upgrade Magento without losing your custom layout, as `config.xml` is a core file.